# List of ISO 639 languages, translated into every ISO 639 language

Tags: localization

I am looking for a set of lists, each containing all the ISO 639 languages localized into each of the languages. I know, this sounds confusing. Here is what I want and can't find:

List1: English

```
LOCALNAME | NATIVE NAME  
English     English  
Spanish     espanol  
German      Deutsch
```

List 2: German

```
LOCALNAME | NATIVE NAME  
Englisch    English  
Spanisch    espaniol  
Deutsch     Deutsch
```

List 3: Spanish

```
LOCALNAME | NATIVE NAME  
inglés      English  
espanol     espaniol  
alemán      Deutsch
```

Alright, I hope this sort of worked with my explanation. I am pretty lost in finding the data for this - I found a french localization, and an english one - but nothing else.

Comment: There's 7000+ ISO 639 languages...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: 49 million pairs? Hmmm...that should be manageable, computationally, but I think most combinations aren't available (as no-one translated them yet). How about just translating each language's native name (e.g. "English, Deutsch, Italiano, Espanol")?

Comment: I have the native names - also, I won't need every combination. Wikipedia has a good list of iso 639 languages, with each in it's native form, english translation and french translation. but that would allow me to fire these terms off to a jobsite only for local translation jobs in english, french and that native language. it's a bit complicated to describe.

Comment: You can find the required data from the Unicode repository at [https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/main](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/main)

Answer (score 5):

"Just" English, French, Spanish, Portuguese, German and native:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AvWRXuU7vsf-dFhyeThRVWd0bHJyeWJOa0FPSzBzVlE&hl=es

Compiled it myself from loc.gov, Wikipedia and some other sources I do not remember. Consider it anything but accurate.

Comment: Link is down: The file has been deleted

Answer (score 1):

A list of all iso 639-1 language codes mapped to the English display name, the native name and a semicolon concatenated list of unique names in all iso languages:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/457027/iso639.txt

I have generated this list using the Java Locale class to generate the display names in various languages:

```
List<Locale> locales = Lists.newArrayList();
Joiner join = Joiner.on(";").skipNulls();
for (String iso : Locale.getISOLanguages()){
  locales.add(new Locale(iso));
}

System.out.println("ISO\tEnglish\tNative\tOthers");
for (Locale loc : locales){
  Set<String> displayNames = Sets.newHashSet();
  for (Locale l2 : locales){
    displayNames.add(loc.getDisplayLanguage(l2).toLowerCase());
  }
  System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", loc.getLanguage().toUpperCase(), loc.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH), loc.getDisplayLanguage(loc), join.join(displayNames)));
}
```

Comment: You'd be better off getting this information from the source, which is the [Unicode CLDR source tree](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/main)

Comment: @MarkusDoring - the link is broken

Comment: For your information, the link mentioned by @alastair-stuart is dead and can now be located at: [https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/main](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/tree/main/common/main)